# Joomla archieve module - displays link to every artilce rather than months

Tags: joomla

I have 3 articles in the archive that have created dates all in January 2015

I have set up the archive module and its displaying one link for each of the articles so i see:

Old News

- January 2015
- January 2015
- January 2015

and each one links in to the archive correctly. I am using joomla 3.4.1

I thought I should only get one link?

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a known bug and there is a patch for it.
see [http://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/6263][1]